# Is it possible to remove Android Gallery access to the SD Card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-gallery

I want to remove the Gallery access to the images stored in the SD Card in order they don't appear visible showup.

I look in the Gallery settings, but didn't fine anything.

Note: there are a lot of folder ini my SD Cards with personal images. This folder are there due to a syncronization (the SD Card is cryprographed).

Answer (score 0):

Sure create an empty file with the name ".nomedia" in the folder where you don't want it to show the images

also clear the cache of your gallery app after that

Comment: No this does not work anymore on modern Android versions.

Comment: Any update? .nomedia still works on my phone (S20) Android 13 - one ui 5.1